# I eat pork with out knowing it’s pork

Tags: food, pork

Aslaam aly qum
I came to France and I have never eaten pork Before but by mistake I bought some food and pork was in it as I don’t read French and I really feel bad and not sure what should I do Now ?
I feel pain in my heart and soul.
Please help and Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Asalamu Alaikum, allah forgives people who do sins by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,
I totally understand what you mean. I live in America and this also happened to me. I took a bite of a sandwich once and then I realized it had bacon. I spit it out as soon as possible, and I also started to cry because of the guilt. I did make dua, but I still felt guilty. My siblings then reminding me that it was a mistake, and all humans make mistakes. We have to remember that Allah (swt) is the most forgiving the most merciful. It is the way that we react to these situations that will test us. If I knowingly knew that it was pork, and continued  to eat it, that would be a sin. However, since we both stopped and made dua, I believe it is a lesson we both learned: Islam is a religion of peace where we have the most Forgiving Creator. :)
Hope that helps.
-Michelle

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum,
If a Muslim eats pork without knowing that what he is eating contains pork, than there is no sin on him however just ask Allah (swt) for forgiveness for he is the most forgiving and merciful. Eating pork is a sin if someone eats it knowing it’s pork or contains pork though. We just have to be careful to not eat anything that is pork or contains pork. I’ve had it happen to me where I’ve eaten things that contained pork without even knowing it as I thought it was just beef only later on to discover that it was beef and pork ‍♂️